# How to make ng-select disabled using Reactive forms?

Tags: angular, select, angular-reactive-forms

How can I make ng-select disabled? I tried [disabled] property, but it does not work here. Also tried to make it disabled using form control, but nothing works.

[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-disabled-g2glws)

Comment: Did you try `ng-disabled`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable/enable a form control when you initialize it by setting `disabled` to `true`

```
creds.push(this.fb.group({
  fruitType: this.fb.control({value: 'Apple', disabled: true})
}));
```

To disable/enable the control later dynamically in your component. You can do so by calling the [disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable)/[enable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#enable) methods for that particular form control.

```
// To enable form control
fruitType.enable();

// To disable form control
fruitType.disable();
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot about this.fb.control to make it disabled, I just initialized it as a simple object.

Comment: @nash11 your answer is totally valid but I just add my answer as an extra information  even it 's not mention in the documentation as it 's possible to pass an object for control initial value 

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to disable ng-select in html using any dynamic condition then you can use `[readonly]` property.

```
<ng-select 
formControlName="myControl"
[readonly]="condition_resolving_to_true_or_false" 
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Getting Error : Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'.

Comment: First check the your letters case, I have written all letters small not like you having having camelcase notation with O capital. Downvote any answer after carefully observing. @Dijo

Answer (score 2):

you can set the value and the disabled state directly by pass an object same @nash11 example but without using `this.fb.control` it will be done internally

```
  addFruits() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.fruits as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      fruitType: { value: 'Apple', disabled: true } // 
    }));
  }
```

in case you want to pass a validator you can use an array and the initial value is an object

```
  addFruits() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.fruits as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      fruitType: [{ value: 'Apple', disabled: true },Validators.required] // 
    }));
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-disabled-v74cq1)

[initialize form control object by FormBuilder](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ca77d1ca902f4df5ba3cc14d80ba705c26aaef09/packages/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L143)